# Zoom pictures in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a picture and a line in a `PictureBox` control. I know how to zoom the picture itself using this code :

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (Globals.x == 1)
        {
            Globals.y = 1;
            Globals.a = e.X;
            Globals.b = e.Y;
        }
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a local version of the graphics object for the PictureBox.
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    if (Globals.y == 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, 470, 353);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, 210, 66, 112, 122);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, 112, 122, 15, 205);
    }

    Bitmap bmpZoom = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    int new4W = bitmap.Width / 3;
    int new4H = bitmap.Height / 3;
    int new2W = bitmap.Width *2/ 3;
    int new2H = bitmap.Height *2/ 3;
    Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(Globals.a - new4W,Globals.b - new4H, new2W, new2H);
    Rectangle dstRect = new Rectangle(60, 10, bmpZoom.Width, bmpZoom.Height);
}
```

My code can zoom the part of the picture that i have clicked on, but when I try to draw the line again, it's in the same location anymore (and that is normal).

I want a solution that can zoom both the picture and the line. If anyone could help me, I would be glad.

Comment: FYI, `Graphics g = e.Graphics;` doesn't create graphics (it's already created before drawing system calls `Paint` event). And as with regards to your question you have following options: 1) draw line on bitmap itself before zooming bitmap 2) zooming line is in fact only changing its coordinates and perhaps scaling thickness 3) don't use `PictureBox`, create more comprehensive control which supports list of figures and can scale (zoom) itself. P.S.: question should be tagged with `winforms`.

Comment: You can scale the Graphics you use to draw the Line using a Matrix from System.Drawing.Drawing2D  and e.Graphics.MultiplyTransform. You will need code to transform points to and fro! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445773/zooming-in-on-quadratic-curve-line-in-c-sharp/28449770?s=1|0.2875#28449770) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633446/how-to-draw-on-zoomable-image-in-c-sharp-windows-forms/28645474?s=2|0.1809#28645474)

Comment: Not trying to be a wiseguy here but you should really try to avoid any type of global variables, and try to come up with more descriptive names than `a` and `b`.